# What is meant by " Scorpions opened for upcoming British band UFO."

Tags: word-choice

Well I've seen that sentence in wiki; an article about a rock band called Scorpions. I'm a little bit confusing on the verb used in this sentence. 
Scorpions opened for upcoming band UFO. What does that mean? What is opened
by Scorpion? That sentence is about one of the tour of the band. So I'm really
eager to know what is opened by Scorpions for UFO. Thank you.

Comment: It means the first act.  The Scorpions will do a set and get the crowd excited in preparation for UFO's appearance.

Comment: I don't believe in UFOs.  Did the crowd have to wait long?

Answer (score 2):

> What is opened by Scorpion?

The concert.  Scorpion opened the concert.

"Scorpions opened for UFO" means that the "Scorpions" band went out on stage first, and primed the audience for the main attraction, "UFO".